# Nested Listbox wont display nested list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

```
   <ListBox Height="434" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,238,0,0" Name="listBox1"             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="432" DataContext="{Binding}"> 

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
                <DataTemplate> 
                    <StackPanel> 
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="4" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"></TextBlock> 
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4"> 
                            <TextBlock Text="Set" Margin="16" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" /> 
                            <TextBlock Text="Weight" Margin="16" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" /> 
                            <TextBlock Text="Reps" Margin="10,16,0,16" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" /> 
                        </StackPanel> 
                        <ListBox Name="setsAndReps" Height="auto" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Sets}"> 
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
                                <DataTemplate> 
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding SetNumber}"/> 
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Weight}"/> 
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Reps}"/> 
                                    </StackPanel> 
                                </DataTemplate> 
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
                        </ListBox> 
                    </StackPanel> 
                </DataTemplate> 
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        </ListBox>
```

The outer listbox's item source is being set to an observable collection of a user defined class called excercise

```
     public class excercise : IComparable, IEquatable<excercise>, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
    string name; 
    int max; 
    int NUM_SETS; 
    ObservableCollection<set> sets; 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return this.name; } 
        set { this.name = value; } 
    } 
    public excercise(string name) 
    { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.NUM_SETS = 0; 
        this.sets = new ObservableCollection<set>(); 
    } 
   public ObservableCollection<set> Sets
    { 
        get{return this.sets; }
    } 
  public ObservableCollection<set> getSets() 
    { 
        return this.sets; 
    } 
}
```

The properties in the inner list box are from the set class but none of them are being displayed and I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: can you show your xaml? makes it easier for us to see whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first listbox doesn't have any itemsource set and the datacontext is set to an empty binding (both on line 1 of your code)

Comment: That fixed it thanks!, i had to remove datacontext. I had been using them interchangeably trying t get it t work what is the difference?

Comment: Here is a good explanation on the difference between datacontext and itemsource: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9bfdb32c-a4ce-46ad-b977-e12d51e815e2/